# Webform CiviCRM Event Confirmation Email Not Sending

Tags: webform-civicrm

CiviCRM 4.7.30, current Webform CiviCRM 7.x-4.19

When 'Send Confirmation Email' = Yes on the CiviEvent, filled out. When the user submits Webform CiviCRM, the event participant is registered successfully but no confirmation email is sent. I reverted the CiviCRM email template for Event Online Registration to default, to rule that out.

Workaround - we made the email send from Webform, but this is a bad workflow for staff who just wants to make CiviEvents.

Does anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must also enable Thank you and Receipting in the CiviCRM Configuration for the Contribution Page associated with the webform;

Comment: Confirmation Screen, Thank you Screen, Send Confirmation Email all have 'Yes' marked. The 'Fees' tab is marked 'No' because it's a free event - is that the issue?

Comment: Right a bit odd - but I think you need to make it a $0 event; with Contribution page all set up - just $0 on check out

Comment: @Karin - I made it a $0 and this did not have the desired effect. Looking at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2435/how-to-trigger-a-confirmation-email-when-registering-participants-via-api, which is the method that the webform uses to do the registration, i see that the API doesn't actually send a confirmation. That makes me think that your method described above would not work. So just wondering if you ever got this working?

Comment: Right.., free events -> with a webform email Thank you for registering - your name; sessions you picked - confirmation and a note that a separate transaction receipt (from CiviCRM) if applicable will follow (if monies were paid); I have used CiviRules as well with extra tokens to create your own receipt.