# Resend all registration confirmation emails for an event

Tags: civievent, registration, confirmation

Is it possible to resend all registration confirmation emails for an event at once?

We have an event with a large number of price set options for different workshops over a weekend. When participants registered, they received the event registration confirmation message which includes details of each event including location with link to a map using the description for the price set option. However, some people registered two months ago and we'd like to send them a reminder that includes all these details the week before the event, so they don't have to dig out that old email to have their personal schedule for the weekend. I can edit each participant individually and resend the confirmation email, but that's going to take a long time for a couple hundred participants. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the [Custom Event Communication](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.eventmessages) extension makes this possible by triggering the email on a change of participant status (in our case, I'll just change all Registered to Attended and trigger on that status change). This is even better than I was hoping, because now I can specify a specific message template instead of having to edit the default one and then change it back.

Edit: If you want to try this, make sure you test this by changing participant status from the drop down menu, rather than by editing the participant, as it seems the tokens for the participant data available to the template can be different in these two situations.

Comment: Great just fyi - the extension can also be used to manually send an email from a participant search result

Comment: Even better, thanks!

Comment: Actually, if you send a message from the participant search results action, {$lineItem} is empty, but from a change in participant status, {$lineItem} has the details for the participant's price set selections - which is what we want here.

Comment: Turns out that I was wrong about this and it does not work: If you change participant status in bulk, $lineItem is not passed to the email template and your recipients will get emails without their price set selections. You only get $lineItem if you edit the participant individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can *almost* do it from advanced search:

1. Display As: Contributions
2. In the contribution section choose financial type Event Fee (or whatever you're using).
3. In the events section choose the event.
4. Search
5. From the actions dropdown choose "receipts - print or email". It's smart enough to use the event message template.

The problem is if they have registered for another event as well, then it will show up in the results too, but you can sort by "source" and then the one event should all be grouped together. The extra results happen because it's finding contacts who have participated in the selected event and listing **all** their contributions that match the criteria in contribution section. If you know something about the contributions, like the date range is unique to this event, then you could further filter in that section and it should only show those.

By the way this also works with searchkit, but it has the same problem. But maybe someone can figure out how to get around it there.

Comment: That's a fun workaround, but in our case we have quite a few participants registered by someone else, who won't show up because they don't have a contribution associated with their contact.